# HTML5 autofocus lost on one-page sites

Tags: html, autofocus

I wonder if someone has the answer to this dilemma? When one has autofocus set on an input element which is not in the page's landing section, autofocus is lost when a user click's a menu tag to go to that section. (e.g. a contact section where there is likely to be a form) ...

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow your question, but in general if you autofocus to work after page load you need to use JavaScript to explicitly set focus, for example http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/v5nujypn/.

Comment: Thank you for your response TJ. I have edited the title to read one-page not on-page (typo), which may have led to your not following my explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: What I need is a method of setting the focus on the first input element of the form in the linked-to section, because clicking the link seems to negate the autofocus I have on that first element.

Comment: Yes it will. For dynamic behavior like this you're going to need JavaScript. Add a click handler to your links and set focus to the appropriate form element there.

Comment: I have hooked up the selector script in the following manner ... (and sorry but I don't have a back-tick on my keyboard)  <script>
 function clickandsetFocus() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");

  var firstElement = pageContainer.querySelector(fname);

  if (firstElement) { 
   firstElement.focus();
  }
 }
 </script>
<a href="#contact" id="contact_link" class="icon fa-envelope" onclick="clickandsetFocus();"><span>Contact me</span></a>

Comment: I am out my depth here I'm afraid ... I have added the following to that script above (I thought "pageContainer" was a js keyword) var pageContainer = document.getElementById("wrapper");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [autofocus attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autofocus) -

> lets you specify that a form control should have input focus **when the
>   page loads**, unless the user overrides it, for example by typing in a
>   different control. **Only one form element in a document** can have the
>   autofocus attribute, which is a Boolean.

Is designed to prompt user agents to give initial focus to a form field when the page loads, providing a less "jarring" and more controllable experience to users of assistive technologies than previous JavaScript based solutions - which often "stole" focus after the user had already began to navigate the document.

The problems with using this attribute in your case are two fold-

1. The page load event will only fire once, and does not fire again when you move focus to a new "page" internally within the same document
2. It is invalid to have more than one element within the same document - in this case your entire single page document - which has the autofocus element.

What you need to do is use the [native JavaScript focus method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus) on a form element of your determination within the new viewport area.

If you have a reference to the new "page" element or container, you could use a class or data-attribute to specify the desired element by using the [querySelector method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) or jQuery.

Something like-

```
var firstElement = pageContainer.querySelector('.focus-field');

if (firstElement) { 
    firstElement.focus();
}
```

Alternatively you could simply use an element selector to select the first form element-

```
var firstElement = pageContainer.querySelector('input, select');

if (firstElement) { 
    firstElement.focus();
}
```

Be aware in this case that it is invalid to focus a hidden input (for hopefully obvious reasons), and if you wish to use this solution it might be best to use the [querySelectorAll method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) and loop through - checking that the type is not hidden and breaking out of the loop on the first valid element to focus. Or simply use attribute selectors and only select inputs of type text.

If you are using jQuery you could use the [not function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude hidden inputs from the selected elements.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as you may see from above I am having problems implementing it. I am not very conversant with javascript I'm afraid (hence this post).

Comment: No I am afraid that your solution didn't solve the problem on an in-page link. It appears to get lost on the link render. (i.e. link, set focus, browser render of link, lose focus). Ah well I'll build a workaround to set focus by a user click on the contact page. But thank you both very much for your help! Can you tell me how I can close this thread?

Comment: I really appreciate your input!